# How to get a 3D array out of PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I am trying to get an array that looks like this using PDO:

```
{
university A {
    year 1 {
        course 1: 10
        course 2: 20
        ...
    }
    year 2 {
        course 1: 15
        course 2: 20
    ...
}
...
university B {
    year 1 {
        course 1: 10
        course 2: 20
        ...
    }
    year 2 {
        course 1: 15
        course 2: 20
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The MySQL output is like this:

```
uni name     year course name number
University A 2014 course_1     10
University A 2014 course_2     18
University A 2015 course_1     15
University A 2015 course_2     20
University B 2014 course_1     10
University B 2014 course_2     18
University B 2015 course_1     15
University B 2015 course_2     20
```

Is there a way to do create a 3 dimensional array from this MySQL result with PDO, or should I rather use PHP to create the array?

Comment: You can't get that format from PDO directly. You need to get the result from PDO as you do now and make that array format manually.

Comment: So I'll use PHP then. Thanks!

Comment: your required output looks like json format. fetch data from DB and add data into array and use `json_encode` function

Comment: MySQL 5.7+ [`JSON_OBJECTAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg) gets you close, but for now, rolling up in PHP is best.